# Performing a search in excel for subtraction based on cell contents

Tags: excel

I am trying to subtract certain cells from 1 single master cell, if other cells contain a certain string.

For example: Cell B2 will be the master with a total dollar amount.

Now, if any row in column C were to contain "text" I want to subtract the number in the same row, but in column D, from B2.

Ergo, if C3 has "text" and D3 has "3", subtract 3 from B2.

My problem is that I don't even know where to start. How do you get a formula to iterate through rows? How do you get that formula to assign the same row to the C and D operations?

Answer (score 0):

If the original formula in **B2** was:

```
=SUM(A:A)
```

then replace it with something like:

```
=SUM(A:A)-SUMPRODUCT(--(C:C="text")*(D:D))
```

[image]